# Exam class multiple choice answers in table format

Tags: exam

I apologize for not having a working example.  But I hope the question (and answer) is simple.

In writing a test question, it is useful to have a table to organize the answers.  Something like this.
    P1 P2 P3
A.     45 mm Hg    20 mm Hg    10 mm Hg
B.     45 mm Hg    35 mm Hg    10 mm Hg
C.     45 mm Hg    45 mm Hg    10 mm Hg
D.     45 mm Hg    45 mm Hg     45 mm Hg
E.     50 mm Hg    35 mm Hg     10 mm Hg

where, obivously P1 P2 and P3 line up with the 2nd-4th columns, and the answer choices in the first column.

Is there a way to embed the \choice function within a table for a particular multiple choice question in the exam document class?

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\pagestyle{head}
\usepackage{tabto}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{20pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
\addtolength{\itemindent}{\labelwidth}%
}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0.5cm}}
%\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

%32
\question 
Which of the following relates a cause to an observed \textbf{\textit{effect}}? \\ (E$ _{\text{m}} $ = resting membrane potential; HR = heart rate; APD = action potential duration; CV = conduction velocity; \scriptsize $\dfrac{\text{dV}}{\text{dt}}$ \normalsize = maximum \scriptsize $\dfrac{\text{dV}}{\text{dt}}$ \normalsize of phase 0; ERP = effective refractory period) \vspace{5mm}
\begin{choices}

\choice CAUSE: blah \tabto{7cm} EFFECT: blah
\choice CAUSE: blah \tabto{7cm} EFFECT: blah
\choice CAUSE: blah \tabto{7cm} EFFECT: blah
\CorrectChoice CAUSE: \tabto{7cm} blah EFFECT: blah
\choice CAUSE: blah \tabto{7cm} EFFECT: blah 

\end{choices}\vspace{5mm}




\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried? It would be nice to see if where it went wrong. So please make a MWE :-)

Comment: I've tired entering \choice as a cell of the table, hoping that the A's, B's, and C's would populate that column, but that's silly thinking.  I've done something similar with tabbing (tabto), but it'd be nice to wrap the answers in a clean table.  I can't put together anything that even remotely works.

Comment: Posted something.  Can those answers be in table proper of some sort, so that maybe a top row is CAUSE and EFFECT instead of what I have?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Found a way to do it as a matching question, followed by the table, so the very small crisis that was existent has been staved off.  But, I'm interested in seeing if the experts can show me how to do this.

Comment: I am also looking for the solution to this one