# How to embed \choices in tabular in exam class?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrays, exam, xspace

Similar to the question: [Exam class multiple choice answers in table format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340278/exam-class-multiple-choice-answers-in-table-format),
I'm trying to embed the `\choices` into a table format and looking like a table.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\printanswers
\newcommand{\wideunderline}[2][2em]{%
  \underline{\makebox[\ifdim\width>#1\width\else#1\fi][c]{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{
When compared to the graph of $y=f(x)$, the graph of $8y=f(-x)$ has been reflected in the \wideunderline[1.5cm]{\textit{i}} and vertically stretched about the x-axis by a factor of \wideunderline[1.5cm]{\textit{ii}}}}\medskip
\begin{questions}
\question The statement above is completed by the information in row:\medskip

\begin{choices}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\choice A
\correctchoice B
\choice C
\choice D
\end{choices}

\question I want choice B embedded in the table. 
%\begin{choices}%%%is this possible?
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    \textbf{Row }& \textbf{\textit{i}}&\textbf{\textit{ii}}\\
    \hline
    A &  $y$-axis&8\\ 
    \hline
        B &  $y$-axis&$\frac{1}{8}$\\%I would like the choice to be embeded i.e. \choice B is in the first column of the table in row 3.
    \hline
        C &  $x$-axis&8\\
    \hline
        D &  $x$-axis&$\frac{1}{8}$\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{choices}%%%%doesn't work. 
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is the difference between your problem and linked post?

Comment: I guess there is no difference.  Since it wasn't answered, I thought I would ask my own question.  Sorry, still new at stack exchange protocol.

Comment: I want to know what does it means "embed `\choices` into a table format and looking like a table"? This means that a 4x2 table that the choices answers sit in the first column of table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `oneparchoices` environment **almost** does what you want but it has two major limitations: First, embedding the choices in a table messes up the handling for `\correctchoice` and second, the formatting automatically adds extra space before each `\choice` after the first which makes sense in the paragraph situation but otherwise not so much.

To get something approaching what you want, I modified the `oneparchoices` environment to remove horizontal spacing and only apply the correct choice formatting to the label rather than the whole answer (which would be challenging to do in a generalizable way given the fact that we're putting the `\choice` commands into cells of a table.

Here's the new environment definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{noparchoices}%
  {%
    \setcounter{choice}{0}%
    \def\choice{%
      \refstepcounter{choice}%
      \choicelabel
      % No need to put the following into a token string; we just put
      % the choicelabel onto the page, so we're at the spot whose page
      % number we want to record:
      \questionobject@pluspagecheck
    }% choice
    \def\CorrectChoice{%
      \refstepcounter{choice}%
      \ifprintanswers
        \begingroup 
        \CorrectChoice@Emphasis
      \fi
      \choicelabel
      \endgroup
      % No need to put the following into a token string; we just put
      % the choicelabel onto the page, so we're at the spot whose page
      % number we want to record:
      \questionobject@pluspagecheck
    }% CorrectChoice
    \let\correctchoice\CorrectChoice
    % If we're continuing the paragraph containing the question,
    % then leave a bit of space before the first choice:
    \ignorespaces
  }%
  {}
\makeatother
```

and here's an example of its use:

```
\begin{noparchoices}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    \textbf{Row }& \textbf{\textit{i}}&\textbf{\textit{ii}}\\
    \hline
    \choice &  $y$-axis&8\\ 
    \hline
        \correctchoice &  $y$-axis&$\frac{1}{8}$\\
    \hline
        \choice &  $x$-axis&8\\
    \hline
        \choice &  $x$-axis&$\frac{1}{8}$\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{noparchoices}
```